# Byobu vs. GNU Screen vs. tmux — usefulness and transferability of skills

Tags: shell, gnu-screen, tmux, byobu

So far I have used [Konsole](https://konsole.kde.org) to manage multiple shell sessions but I haven't tried [Byobu](http://byobu.co), [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/), and [tmux](http://tmux.github.io), which offer better support for multiple shells.  They all share one main feature, which is to allow detaching the current session and later reattaching to that old session.

To help me pick a tool to learn, I'd like to know: how do they differ in the following respects?

1. Features (obviously)
2. Project maturity. I do not want to learn a tool that is changing too much. Enhancements are welcome, but I don't like surprises such as disappearing features.
3. Learning curve
4. Availability in different platforms. If I learn a tool, I'd like to be able to use it on a FreeBSD server, SuSE desktop, or Ubuntu.
5. Compatibility with other interactive shell programs. Can I still use `vim` and `emacs -nw` (non-window mode, or text mode) the same way I am used to? Will the keyboard shortcuts conflict with the ones of other tools?

I just tried all of them and Byobu looks like a sort of front end for GNU Screen and tmux. Then why did someone create Byobu instead of contributing to the GNU screen project and adding new features? Why is Byobu not some sort of advanced interface mode in GNU Screen? If I use Byobu as my daily tool with GNU screen as the backend, can I transfer this knowledge to use GNU Screen without Byobu if a certain machine only has GNU Screen?

Comment: Commenting my own question. After I posted, I just saw the number of times each tag was used in StackExchange:

gnu-screen: 199 times
tmux: 125 times
byobu: 18 times

Does that mean byobu is still not popular? Or that byobu is so intuitive that no one has any question on how to use it?

Comment: Because `byobu` is just a fork of `screen` with extra features, so the `gnu-screen` tag applies.

Comment: According to the documentation (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/byobu.1.html) the default configuration of Byobu is to use tmux as the default backend. If byobu is a fork of gnu screen, does that mean tmux is better than gnu screen?

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that it supports tmux now, although it remains just a wrapper script -- not even a fork apparently. But yes, tmux is in some ways better than Screen (at least [their FAQ](http://tmux.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tmux/trunk/FAQ) claims so).

Comment: Byobu is not a fork of anything!  It's a layer on top of Screen and Tmux, similar to Gnome/KDE being a layer on top of Xorg.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

For Tmux vs GNU Screen, read

- [tmux vs. screen [SU]](https://superuser.com/q/236158/49184)
- [tmux vs. GNU Screen [Unix.SX]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/549)

and several other comparison incarnations that can be found on blogs and such.

Some general terms that are oft repeated:

- Tmux is newer. This means it is a bit fancier (simple vertical splitting, nice green lines) and a bit less well tested for e.g. compatibility (to negligible extent according to its proponents).
- Tmux is leaner on resources.
- GNU Screen is found everywhere and is most probably still more used.

Apart from this, one can look at specific functions for one or the other alternative, and personal preference will dominate the discussion. I personally used to use GNU Screen heavily — now I use Tmux.

I have not found Byobu to have any "killer features" for me. It provides an abstraction where I believe none is needed for my use cases.

---

Another way to look at it is to note that Byobu can use either of GNU Screen or Tmux as backend, which shows that the differences from a user POV are mostly superficial.

Answer (score 320):

Great question!  *For what it's worth, I'm the author and maintainer of [Byobu](https://www.byobu.org/).*

[Byobu](https://www.byobu.org/) is a configuration layer, originally written to sit on top of [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/), but now also works on top of [Tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/).

I started writing Byobu back in [December of 2008](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Ekirkland/byobu/trunk/revision/1), as I met up with a bunch of Screen and Ubuntu Server users at the [Googleplex](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UDSJaunty) and found that *all* of us maintained our own bunch of neat/fun/useful hacks in our `~/.screenrc` configurations.  And we had to manually move those around between the dozens or hundreds of servers we used.  We started trading tips and tricks, and I began to collect those into the original [GPLv3](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.txt) project called "screen-profiles".  About 6 months later, a whole community had developed around "[screen-profiles](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2009/01/ubuntu-jaunty-testing-screen-profiles.html)" and the project became much more than just screen hacks -- we had configuration utilities, live status plugins, and keybindings.  So we [renamed the project](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2009/05/byobu-20-released-project-formerly.html) "Byobu", which is a Japanese word for those elegant, folding "screens", and has the added benefit of being able to more successfully Google for "Byobu $FOO" than "Screen $FOO".

With Byobu now in most Linux distributions ([Ubuntu](http://pad.lv/u/byobu), [Debian](http://packages.qa.debian.org/b/byobu.html), [Fedora](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/applications/Byobu%20Window%20Manager), [Arch](http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=28295)), and functional on  most Macs/BSDs and other UNIXes, it give the same look-and-feel, convenient keybindings, dynamic system status information at any terminal you might need to access.

Why not contribute back to the GNU Screen project?  A couple of reasons...  All of what Byobu works just as well as configuration options.  None of it *needs* to be included in the Screen source base to be functional.  Some things might work better or perform nicer if Screen included them by default, but many of the changes are very "opinionated", which are usually difficult or impossible to contribute to a [25-year-old](https://groups.google.com/group/net.sources/browse_thread/thread/e55f5059d2329d36?pli=1) upstream project.  Also, the GNU Screen project is moving very slowly, if at all.  It's 25+ years old, and hasn't had an official release since [August of 2008](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/screen/).  Every distribution is carrying huge stacks of patches just to keep your /usr/bin/screen working and secure.  e.g., Ubuntu and Debian are currently carrying 19K lines of code in ~48 [patches](http://patches.ubuntu.com/s/screen/screen_4.0.3-14ubuntu8.patch).

I learned of Tmux about 2 years ago, and really fell in love with the source code, design,  interface, and active community!  I've had a much easier time [contributing fixes](http://tmux.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tmux?view=revision&revision=2535) to upstream Tmux and discussing topics on the mailing list.  And as a Byobu user who uses it everywhere, I wanted the same look and feel to my Tmux sessions as what I had come to enjoy in 4+ years of Byobu.  So I [ported](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2011/06/anyone-interested-in-byobu-profiles-for.html) all of the Byobu code to work equally well with Tmux as the backend, as Screen.  As of the [Byobu 5.0 release](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2011/12/byobu-5-released.html), Tmux is now the default backend, with Screen still supported in a legacy mode.  Byobu now leverages many of the modern features of Tmux over Screen, including vastly improved 256-color support, UTF8 characters, and horizontal/vertical window splitting.

If you're satisfied with the default settings in Screen or Tmux, or want to write your own configuration files from scratch, then by all means, Screen and Tmux as fantastic utilities that have added many years of efficiency to our lives.  If you're interested in a set of configurations that really stretch and extend what Screen and Tmux does out of the box, have a look at Byobu!

Cheers,
Dustin

Comment: Good explanation.  Amazing that screen is so heavily patched - does it need a new maintainer or something?  And byobu is great - thanks.

Comment: I wish I could up-vote twice. I've been using byobu for years now and have only just recently learned of the complexity that it's been hiding me from all this time.

Comment: I always use `CTRL+\` as escape.  With `screen` and `tmux` this works like a charm, but not with `byobu` (Debian 7.1 Wheezy).

Comment: Now that `screen` has got a new maintainer and development seems to have picked up steam, do things change?

Comment: Couldn't those opinionated defaults make it the younger tmux project? It seems the answer is missing a paragraph "Why not contribute back to the tmux project?" https://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: @user2707671 The OP said explicitely "I've had a much easier time contributing fixes to upstream Tmux and discussing topics on the mailing list."

Comment: Byobu seems to be finally the persistent terminal that behaves like any modern terminal.

Answer (score 15):

From an actual use case, the biggest difference between `screen` and `tmux` is how they handle split windows.

A window in `screen` is a single pseudo-terminal. When attached to a `screen` session, you can split your terminal into multiple regions, each of which can display a `screen` window. Multiple regions can display the same window. The splits are not part of the session; if you detach, your splits are gone.

A window in `tmux` consists of one or more pseudo-terminals, one per pane. This means that panes persist if you detach and reattach later. It also means that you can display only one window at a time in `tmux`, and that panes cannot be shared among multiple windows. `tmux` does *allow* a window to be shared among multiple sessions, however.

I prefer the model used by `tmux`, but I couldn't argue that it is better than the model used by `screen`.

Comment: The argument pro `tmux` is the [Deutsche Bahn](http://bahn.de).  Ride a fast train, try to work over `ssh` using a mobile connection and you will quickly see that the `tmux` model is far superior, because after one of the frequent connection breaks you do not need to re-arrange all the panes on your jumphost after relogin.  SCNR

Comment: if you are facing frequent disconnections, I suggest looking into [mosh](https://mosh.org/) which can recover automatically from lost signal, unlike `ssh`

Answer (score 8):

For me, the deal-breaker for tmux was the implementation of session sharing.

In GNU Screen, if you let another user connect to a session, or simply have your session connected to more than one terminal, they can operate independently (switching screens in a session A from terminal B doesn't make terminal A also switch screens in session A).

The above is not the case with tmux (yet?) or I haven't been able to find a way to change the behavior yet.

If someone knows of a way to change this behavior in tmux or if tmux updates to change this behavior or give the option to now change this behavior, please leave a comment.

Comment: `tmux` has a notion of "linked" sessions with `new-session -t shared`. Windows from 'shared' appear in the new session, new windows in one appear in the other, and closing a window in one closes it in the other. However, which window each client sees is specific to the actual session it attaches.