# How to enter an existing R shell from command line linux

Tags: linux, terminal, r

All,

I'm accessing a remote server via SSH and running an R process on that server. We're in development right now, so it's important for me to enter the R shell and run line by line commands. Last night I logged on to the server, sent a bunch of code to the shell, and called it a night. This morning, when I tried to get back into the shell I found that I had a broken pipe and needed to reestablish the connection. Unfortunately, this also took me out of the R shell.

Is there a way to, from a command line linux interface, re-enter the shell/workspace of an existing R process? I've attached a display of system processes with the one I'm interested in highlighted.

Cheers, 
Aaron [image]

Comment: when shell dies, R should have died too. why is it still alive?

Comment: right, my fault--that's actually a different process in the same directory. the r process is dead. thanks for your help. i'm working to get tmux up and running now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Going Forward

You should be running `R` under [`gnu screen` or `tmux`](https://superuser.com/questions/423310/byobu-versus-gnu-screen-versus-tmux).

See also [emacs tramp over an unreliable connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819248/emacs-tramp-over-an-unreliable-connection) if you want to use Emacs/ESS.

### Existing Process

As for communicating with an existing process (whether `R` or shell), I suggest that you try to write to its handle available via the `proc` filesystem.

E.g.,

```
$ echo here >> /proc/$$/fd/1
here
```

where `$$` is the current shell's PID and `1` is the `stdout`.
You can try to echo a command into `0` (`stdin`).
This might not work though...

Comment: tmux or gnu screen look like they'll get me what i want going forward. any way for me to get into the shell that exists currently? thanks for the help.